# web service alternatives to map drives

Tags: c#, web-services

a requirement for  project is to have my winforms system to be able to see a central file repository (central folder of scanned documents). users need to be able to read, and delete and save files.

to do this the server had a shared folder, and every client had a map drive to the folder.
from experience i have found map drives to be a real pain in the but. sometimes u hit security issues, sometimes map drives just go wonky.

i would prefer to avoid this design, and rather have a webservice that publishes a list of files, another service that returns a file, deletes file etc etc.

but it feels like this must have been done before plenty times. rather than rolling my own, has anyone implemented or seen something similar?

Server is windows with IIS, and I am on the ms stack so would make sense to have something that fits into that.

Comment: googling led me back to stackoverflow which led me to these: http://ajaxplorer.info/ ; http://www.filemanager.net ; http://www.webfileexplorer.com/ peoples reports about them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209103/what-is-the-best-web-based-file-explorer

Comment: Webdav may be of interest too. Basically a read/write file system via http. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV . I'm not sure how much support there is for coding with them in c#. You may well need to go find 3rd party APIs.